# Validating a text input to use only lower cases and numbers 0 to 9 when a link is clicked

Tags: validation

I am making a simple web app that reads short URLs from a specific domain and then opens the short URL in the existing Internet browser. The functionality is already working but I am a bit confused on how to move forward in adding input validations to make the system more self service. I would like to validate a text input field which is not using a form.  I want the text field to support only small case and numbers 0 to 9.  I've found some solutions here in forum but I am not capable of fully integrating the offered solutions because most of them use forms and my programming skill is beginner's level. My input field uses the  link anchor and looks like this:

```
<input type="text" id="keyword" placeholder="Small letters only" />
<a class="btn" href="http://mysite.com" id="domain"></a>
```

I need to add the following functions in my jquery script:

1. When the link is clicked, the script will check if the character string provided in "keyword" are lowercase and numbers only. if user inputs a character other than lowercase letters and numbers, alert message pops up "Invalid character detected. Try again".
2. If no input was provided when the link is clicked, alert message pops up "Provide an input." .
3. When the input is valid, the script below is run.

Thank you for your assistance.

```
$(function()
    {
    $('#domain').click( function() 
       {
    window.location = $(this).attr('href') + '/' + $('#keyword').val();
    return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regular Expressions for this validation.

```
$(function {
    $('#domain').click( function() {
        var val = $('#keyword').val();
        if (val == '') {  /* popup time */ }
        var regexp = new RegExp("[a-z0-9]+");
        if (regexp.match(val)) { /* Redirect */ }
        else { /* invalid characters */ }
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks Imre, I'll try to check if it will work.  I was able to make the one I did work for Safari but it wouldnt work on FireFox and Chrome (Mac) but works on Firefox Windows but not on Windows IE and Chrome.